# Converting a vector in cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

This is my problem.  I have the vector: $$\vec A=10\hat i$$  at the point P(-3, 2, 4). Convert that vector to spherical coordinates.

I need to use a conversion matriz to find the components $A_r$, $A_\phi$, $A_\theta$. The final answer is $$\vec A=-(5.56\hat r+5.56\hat\phi+6.18\hat\theta)$$

I know how to get the answer, what I don´t understand is:

1) What does it mean vector: $\vec A=10\hat i$ at point P(-3, 2, 4). How can I interpret this.

2) What does it mean the answer $\vec A=-(5.56\hat r+5.56\hat\phi+6.18\hat\theta)$.  How can I see this at the spherical coordinates.

It is supposed that both vectors must be equals, in fact the magnitude of both is $10$.

Thank you.